# Transposing values in a column of a Pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a data frame containing the values of the 'atoms' column in df1 transposed, so that the resulting data frame looks like df2.

#### df1:

```
    name    atoms
0   CH4     C
1   CH4     H
2   CH4     H
3   CH4     H
4   CH4     H
5   NH3     N
6   NH3     H
7   NH3     H
8   NH3     H
```

#### df2:

```
    name    a0  a1  a2  a3  a4
0   CH4     C   H   H   H   H
1   CH4     C   H   H   H   H
2   CH4     C   H   H   H   H
3   CH4     C   H   H   H   H
4   CH4     C   H   H   H   H
5   NH3     N   H   H   H   NaN
6   NH3     N   H   H   H   NaN
7   NH3     N   H   H   H   NaN
8   NH3     N   H   H   H   NaN
```

Is there a way to achieve this using Pandas?
 I used groupby for this as follows:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['name','a0','a1','a2','a3','a4'], index=np.arange(9))

c = df1.groupby('name')

df2['name'] = df1['name']

for mol in df1.name.unique():

    df2.iloc[c.indices[mol],np.arange(1,len(c.indices[mol]) +1)] = c.get_group(mol)['atoms'].values
```

But I feel like there should be a less complicated and faster way to do this.

Comment: @Akaisteph7 This question is specific enough to be on-topic on Stack Overflow. Code Review prefers questions with more context than this. Please see [A Guide to Code Review for SO users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5777/31562)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly a `crosstab`, but with a couple additional steps.

```
u = df.assign(key=df.groupby('name').cumcount()).set_index('name')

i = pd.crosstab(u.index, u['key'], u['atoms'], aggfunc='first')

# Cleanup and formatting
i.reindex(u.index).add_prefix('a').rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index()
```

```
  name a0 a1 a2 a3   a4
0  CH4  C  H  H  H    H
1  CH4  C  H  H  H    H
2  CH4  C  H  H  H    H
3  CH4  C  H  H  H    H
4  CH4  C  H  H  H    H
5  NH3  N  H  H  H  NaN
6  NH3  N  H  H  H  NaN
7  NH3  N  H  H  H  NaN
8  NH3  N  H  H  H  NaN
```

Comment: Thanks. Your code takes about 40% less time than mine.